# Number of occurences of a String in all files using GNU parallel

Tags: unix, gnu-parallel

I am trying to get count of a particular string from all the files in a directory

so i used find -name "application.log*" | parallel zgrep -c "Instructions before" {}

my expectation was it will count of string "Instructions before" on all the application.log files

but instead it actually gives the output something like this

```
find -name "application.log*" | parallel zgrep -c "Instructions before" {}
./application.log.2020-05-22-08-24.gz:0
gzip: before.gz: No such file or directory
before:0
./application.log.2020-05-22-08-22.gz:0
gzip: before.gz: No such file or directory
before:0
./application.log.2020-05-22-08-29.gz:0
gzip: before.gz: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a quoting issue. Quotes are eaten by the shell, so each `zgrep` process is invoked as `zgrep -c Instructions before ./application.log.blah.gz`, with `Instructions` taken as the string to search for, and `before` one of the files to search - `zgrep` apparently adds the `.gz` extension if missing.

So you need to quote the quotes:

```
find -name "application.log*" -print0 | parallel -0 zgrep -c '"Instructions before"' {}
```

or tell `parallel` to do it for you:

```
find -name "application.log*" -print0 | parallel -0q zgrep -c "Instructions before" {}
```

And if all the files you care about are in the same directory and not also in subdirectories, see Mark's comment for a simpler way that avoids the `find`.

Comment: If, as OP states, files are all in one directory, the command can be made simpler and more reliable by using `parallel -q zgrep -c "Instructions before" ::: application.log*`